# A set of mouse/keyboard actions Java program

Tags: java

I want to build a program that does the following:

1. User clicks on a button (like on a GUI) to record his/hers movements.
   Then, the user does a set of actions on the computer - this could be clicking on file explorer and deleting/creating/renaming a file, opening Chrome or another program etc... basically a few keyboard/mouse movements.
2. Then the user can specify a time at which the program should replicate this recording of movements. (The program hasn't been stopped and it uses the current time of the computer's clock to know when to do it)

Can I do something like this in Java? Searched quite a bit and couldn't see something relevant. The only thing that came to my mind since I am still a beginner is MouseEvents etc but I don't think these can be done outside the frames of GUI.

Thanks in advance I am keen to build this project!

Comment: `but I dont think these can be done outside the frames of the GUI` - you might be able to use the `Robot` class. It allows you to generate mouse/keyboard events at the OS level.

Comment: While technically you can send events using the Robot class, you will be doing so blind. The Robot class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) cannot tell you what is at the pixel you are going to click. Anything unexpected (like antivirus popping up a dialog, browser opening a popup or another window) will seriously ruin your day. Native code is the better way to go, as that allows you to get information on existing windows. If you want this functionality instead of a hobby project, you can use something like AutoHotKey (https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: @KCWong Can you tell me more about what you mean by native code and how I can do it ? I want to build this is a hobby project.

Comment: @curiosityIsBliss I was talking about using c++; with Windows API like FindWindowEx (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx). Also check out the other Windows functions like EnumWindows. These functions allow you to get handles and information of windows and buttons.

Comment: @KCWong so it is not possible in java ?

Comment: Technically you can use Java Native Interface (JNI, the official way, requires c++ knowledge, difficult for new programmers) or Java Native Access (JNI, a third-party package, easier to use but bad performance compared to JNI, https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). With either option you expose the native APIs to Java and call them from there. If you are new to Java, I'd recommend using Robot, ignore the native stuff, and just accept that your program requires the GUI to be in a predictable state to work. Return to JNI/JNA later when you are better prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNativeHook is worth looking into for this and similar purposes. I found it helpful.

https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook